# emberjs how to fire a jquery effect after model is load

Tags: jquery, ember.js

I start to use Emberjs :)
I am trying to display pictures from model with a fadein jquery effect

```
$('.ember-view img').load( ->
  $(this).fadeIn(10000).show()
).each( ->
  $(this).load() if(this.complete) 
)
```

I tried differents way to find the good place to fire this event but I was not able to find the good place to create a method to fire this event

I have this route

```
MyApp.SquaresRoute = Ember.Route.extend(
 setupController: (controller) ->
   controller.set('model', @store.find('sqimage'))
```

I have also 2 controllers (the array and the object)

```
MyApp.SquaresController = Ember.ArrayController.extend

MyApp.SquareController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
```

and my template where I render my objects

```
 {{#each controller}}
    <img {{bind-attr src="url_thumbnail"}} {{bind-attr style="style"}} />
{{/each}}
```

I tried to put a didInsertElement in the view file but it didnt work.

Should I use an observer ? Where should I put it ?

Thanks a million for your answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to use a separate view for each of your collection items. The code should look something like this:

**Handlebars Template for your collection:**

```
{{#each item in controller}}
    {{view App.ItemView context=item}}
{{/each}}
```

**Handlebars Template for your ItemView:**

```
<img {{bind-attr src="url_thumbnail"}} {{bind-attr style="style"}} />
```

**And do the jquery effect within the Views didInsertElement hook:**

```
App.YourView = Ember.View.extend({
  // these are two different styles to use the 'didInsertElement' hook. Choose the one you prefer
  didInsertElement : function(){
    this.$().find('img').fadeIn(10000);
  },
  yourEffectFunction : function(){
    this.$().find('img').fadeIn(10000);
  }.on("didInsertElement")
});
```

**Plz note:** I did not really understand what your jquery code should do. So just replace the logic within the View with the desired code.

Comment: just an edit we need to target the img element and not view container so i thinki we should edit your post

Comment: Glad it works. :-) Mark the answer as accepted as guidance for other users plz.